# Creating SQLite Database with RecyclerView and Tablayout

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-database

I need to create an SQLite database with RecyclerView in which I've already tried searching for all the samples but none so far suited my need. Most of them can't be comprehended since I couldn't understand their structure eg their folders, java classe, etc. I've been trying to figure that out myself for many days but couldn't find a valuable solutions. I'll go straight to the point, I need to understand how to read my sqlite database to the recyclerview basically only the field terms should show up. For the time being, the insertion of data are hardcoded for now since I want to see if my database is working which suddenly doesn't.

Here is my DatabaseHelper.java:

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.DataModel;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBASE = "my_notes";
    public static final String TBLMYNOTES = "tblnotes";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String NOTE_TERM = "note_term";
    public static final String NOTE_ID = "note_id";
    public static final String NOTE_DEF = "note_def";
    public static final String NOTE_SYNTAX = "note_syntax";
    public static final String NOTE_CODE = "note_code";

    public int currentID;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBASE, null, DBVERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TBLMYNOTES+" ("+ NOTE_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+NOTE_TERM+" TEXT, "+NOTE_DEF+" TEXT, "+NOTE_SYNTAX+" TEXT, "+NOTE_CODE+" TEXT )");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TBLMYNOTES);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long InsertNewRecord( String tblname, ArrayList<String> fields, ArrayList<String> values ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues db_values = new ContentValues();

        int countArr = values.size();

        for( int i = 0; i < countArr; i++  ) {

            db_values.put( fields.get(i), values.get(i) );

        }

        long status = db.insert(TBLMYNOTES, null, db_values);

        return status;
    }


    public Cursor getAllData(String tblname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+tblname, null);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    public List<DataModel> getAllDataModel(){

        List<DataModel> dataList = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TBLMYNOTES;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        while(c.moveToNext()){
            /**     DataModel model= new DataModel();
            model.setId(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)));
            model.setTerm(c.getString(1));
            model.setDefinition(c.getString(2));
            model.setSyntax(c.getString(3));
            model.setCode(c.getString(4));
    */  
            int index0 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_ID);
            int index1 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_TERM);
            int index2 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_DEF);
            int index3 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_SYNTAX);
            int index4 = c.getColumnIndex(NOTE_CODE);

            int id = c.getInt(index0);

            String term = c.getString(index1);
            String def = c.getString(index2);
            String syn = c.getString(index3);
            String code = c.getString(index4);
            DataModel model = new DataModel(id, term, def, syn, code);
            dataList.add(model);

        }

        return dataList;
    }

    public int DeleteRecord(String tblname, String strField, String strValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int status = db.delete(TBLMYNOTES , " "+strField+" = ? ", new String[] { strValue });

        return status;
    }

    public int UpdateRecord(String tblname, ArrayList<String> Fields, ArrayList<String> Values) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues db_values = new ContentValues();

        int countMaxArr = Fields.size();

        String strFieldID = Fields.get(0);
        String strFieldValue = Values.get(0);


        for( int i = 0; i < countMaxArr; i++ ) {

            db_values.put(Fields.get(i), Values.get(i));

        }

        int status = db.update(TBLMYNOTES, db_values, strFieldID+" = ? ", new String[] { strFieldValue });

        return status;
    }

    public void setcurrID(int ID) {     
        currentID = ID;
    }       

    public int getcurrID() {
        return currentID;
    }


    public Cursor getRecordByID(String tblname, String Fieldname, String Fieldvalue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TBLMYNOTES+" WHERE "+Fieldname+" = "+Fieldvalue, null);

        return result;

    }


}
```

This is the My_Notes that displays the list of terms in recyclerview:
for now I coded the insertion of database manually inside here to test if my database is working but to no avail did it do me any good.

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes.My_Notes_Add_Main;
import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper;

public class My_Notes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
    static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> removedItems;
    private ImageButton addNote;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_notes);

        //database
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        ArrayList<String> ArrValues = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        ArrayList<String> FieldsArr = new ArrayList<String>();


        ArrValues.add("Hierarchy");
        ArrValues.add("Definition Here!");
        ArrValues.add("Syntax Here!");
        ArrValues.add("Code Here!");


        FieldsArr.add( "NOTE_TERM" );
        FieldsArr.add( "NOTE_DEF" );
        FieldsArr.add( "NOTE_SYNTAX" );
        FieldsArr.add( "NOTE_CODE" );


        db.InsertNewRecord("TBLMYNOTES", FieldsArr, ArrValues);

       // myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(this);
        addNote = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addNotes);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_notes_recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(db.getAllDataModel()));






        btnAdd();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void btnAdd(){
        addNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),My_Notes_Add_Main.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

This is my DataModel.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

public class DataModel {

    String term_;
    String definition_;
    int id_;
    String syntax_;
    String code_;

    public DataModel(){

    }

    public DataModel(int id, String term, String def, String syntax, String code) {
        this.term_ = term;
        this.id_ = id;
        this.definition_=def;
        this.syntax_=syntax;
        this.code_=code;
    }

    public String getTerm() {
        return term_;
    } 

    public String getDefinition(){
        return definition_;
    }

    public String getSyntax() {
        return syntax_;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code_;
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id_;
    }

    public void setTerm(String term){
        this.term_= term;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id_= id;
    }
    public void setDefinition(String definition){
        this.definition_= definition;
    }
    public void setSyntax(String syntax){
        this.syntax_= syntax;
    }
    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code_= code;
    }
}
```

This is my CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    private List<DataModel> items;

    public CustomAdapter(List<DataModel> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTerm;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewTerm = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTerm);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_notes_card_view, parent, false);

        //view.setOnClickListener(My_Notes.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        holder.textViewTerm.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getTerm());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

For my libraries I have this here:
I'm using eclipse so I have no idea what version they are

> ```
>  android-support-v7-appcompat 
>  cardview
>  design
>  recyclerview
> ```

My Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.index.Index_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.My_Notes"
            >            
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes.My_Notes_Add_Main"
            >            
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT HERE:

My_Note_Add_Main.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class My_Notes_Add_Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int numOfPages = 4; //viewpager has 4 pages
    private final String[] pageTitle = {"Terms", "Definition", "Syntax", "Code"};
    private ImageButton addNew;
    private EditText terms, def, syn, code;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_notes_add_main);

        addNew = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.addNew);
        addNewTerms();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPages; i++) {
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(pageTitle[i]));
        }

        //set gravity for tab bar
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), numOfPages);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));
    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

  /**  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_notes_add_main_menu, menu);        
        return true;
    } */

    public void addNewTerms(){
        addNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Add Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }






}
```

My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

public class My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int numOfTabs;

    public My_Notes_Add_MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       return My_Notes_Add_TabFragment.getInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

My_Notes_Add_Tab_Fragment.java

```
package com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.addNotes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.R;

public class My_Notes_Add_TabFragment extends Fragment {

    private int position;
    private TextView content;
    private ImageView image;

    public static Fragment getInstance(int position) {
        My_Notes_Add_TabFragment f = new My_Notes_Add_TabFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //get data from Argument
        position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_notes_add_tab_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        content = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }


}
```

Added Logcat:

```
03-14 00:33:11.446: E/SQLiteLog(16725): (1) near "FROMtblnotes": syntax error
03-14 00:33:11.446: D/AndroidRuntime(16725): Shutting down VM
03-14 00:33:11.446: W/dalvikvm(16725): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x55d91b20)
03-14 00:33:11.446: D/AndroidRuntime(16725): procName from cmdline: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 00:33:11.446: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 00:33:11.446: D/AndroidRuntime(16725): file written successfully with content: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite StringBuffer : ;com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite
03-14 00:33:11.456: I/Process(16725): Sending signal. PID: 16725 SIG: 9
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): Process: com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite, PID: 16725
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite/com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.My_Notes}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMtblnotes": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMtblnotes
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROMtblnotes": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROMtblnotes
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.mynote_databases.DatabaseHelper.getAllDataModel(DatabaseHelper.java:84)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at com.zaid.recyclerviewsqlite.notes.My_Notes.onCreate(My_Notes.java:64)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-14 00:33:11.456: E/AndroidRuntime(16725):    ... 11 more
03-14 00:33:11.606: W/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-14 00:33:11.606: I/dalvikvm(16740): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-14 00:33:11.606: W/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18104: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-14 00:33:11.606: D/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-14 00:33:11.606: I/dalvikvm(16740): Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-14 00:33:11.606: W/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18108: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-14 00:33:11.606: D/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-14 00:33:11.636: I/dalvikvm(16740): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-14 00:33:11.636: W/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-14 00:33:11.636: D/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-14 00:33:11.636: I/dalvikvm(16740): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-14 00:33:11.636: W/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-14 00:33:11.636: D/dalvikvm(16740): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
```

Comment: *...if my database is working which suddenly doesn't.* - Please explain what exactly happens when you run your code. Do you get an exception(in which case you need to post the stacktrace from logcat), you don't get any data(in which case log your methods to see what is happening) etc...

Comment: @Luksprog my apologies for not being detailed enough it just so happens that my project got crash when I open it. Should I add the logcat then I'm going to edit my post and add my tablayout java.

Comment: If your app crashes then you need to post the stacktrace from logcat to see why it crashes.

Comment: @Luksprog updated the post now. Here's the brief problem from the completed coded above. App crashes when I tried to run it on my emulator.

Comment: The exception is telling you that you're trying to run a bad sql command : *SELECT * FROMtblnotes* which comes from the line *String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TBLMYNOTES;* in the getAllDataModel() method. Notice that you need to put a space after *FROM* to split it from the table name (like you already did in getAllData()).

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for your effort in helping fortunately I've already solved the issue. But can I ask for your help should you be available. As you can see I'm now trying to create an insertion of database (not the hardcoded one) via the user input inside the edittextView of the 4 tabs from my My_Notes_Add_Main.java. But my problem is that I don't know how to fetch each data that was inserted from editTextView since I have no idea how to call their position considering I only have 1 viewPager that has the EditTextView which is also just 1.